# regarding functions in bash

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I have a general doubt regarding how to works functions in bash, let me explain, I have the next script called testscript.sh and it contains the following :

```
#!/bin/bash

   export var="some text"

function clock {
   # some arguments
   echo "the variable var is [$var]"
}

$@
```

So when i run the script in the next way :
.

```
/testscript.sh clock
```

The value of "var" is empty unless i put inside of the function, so the question here is : is there any method to call the individually functions as I'm trying to do and all the variables outside of them i can call them inside the functions ?

thanks

Comment: Add `set -x` to the top of your script and run it again and paste the output.

Comment: Thanks, my problem was that i called the script from anoter script, for that reason the variables does not appears :)

Comment: That's not a reason. That shouldn't change anything.

Answer (score 3):

I beg to differ, as per the following transcript:

```
pax> cat testscript.sh
#!/bin/bash

   export var="some text"

function clock {
   # some arguments
   echo "the variable var is [$var]"
}

$@

pax> ./testscript.sh clock
the variable var is [some text]
```

As you can see there, the variable is very *much* set to the expected value. Hence, if it's coming out blank, you have an issue not related to the code you've shown us.